# Get max of 8 words from first sentence in string

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to write a function that returns only the first eight words of a sentence. However, if the first sentence is shorter than eight words, I want to only return the first sentence - not the first eight words.

For example if the tested sentence was "This is a sentence that is much longer than eight words, but only the first eight words will be outputted."

The output would be: "This is a sentence that is much longer"

If I added punctuation (that the function looks for) to change the input to "This is a sentence. that is much longer than eight words, but only the first eight words will be outputted."

The output would be: "This is a sentence."

Here's the code:

```js
function checkString(string) {
  var splitSentence = string.split(" ");
  var firstEightWords = splitSentence.slice(0, 8);
  var joinedString = firstEightWords.join(" ")
  var chars = joinedString.split("")
  for (var x = 0; x < chars.length; x++) {
    if ((chars[x] === ".") || (chars[x] === "?") || (chars[x] === "!")) {
      var finalProduct = chars.slice(0, x + 1).join("");
      return finalProduct;
    } else {
      return firstEightWords
    }
  }
};

var str = checkString("This is a sentence that is much longer than eight words, but only the first eight words will be outputted.");

console.log(str);
```

Comment: What is the first sentence is less than eight words?

Comment: @jro, yeah in my if statement the function looks for the either .! or ?

Comment: You can use string.split(".") to split into sentences d delimited by .. You could use some regex for this

Comment: @JackCollins Split the string with punctuation then check if its length is greater than 8 char if yes then take a substring of it and return otherwise return as it is..

Answer (score 2):

Seems like what may be confusing you is splitting your string into an array of words before you deal with the sentence delimiters. Just deal with the sentence delimiters first and then you can just use slice to limit the number of words to a maximum of 8.

Slightly more compact version using just `split`, `slice`, and `join`:

```js
const longer = 'This is a sentence that is much longer than eight words, but only the first eight words will be outputted.';
const shorter = 'This is a sentence. that is much longer than eight words, but only the first eight words will be outputted.';
const trunc = (s) => s.split(/[.?!]/)[0].split(' ').slice(0, 8).join(' ');
console.log(trunc(longer));
// This is a sentence that is much longer

console.log(trunc(shorter));
// This is a sentence
```

If you need to retain the end punctuation for sentences with 8 words or less, then you can add `search` into the mix:

```js
const longer = 'This is a sentence that is much longer than eight words, but only the first eight words will be outputted.';
const shorter = 'This is a sentence. that is much longer than eight words, but only the first eight words will be outputted.';
const trunc = (s) => {
  const i = s.search(/[.?!]/) + 1;
  return s.slice(0, i ? i : s.length).split(' ').slice(0, 8).join(' ');
};

console.log(trunc(longer));
// This is a sentence that is much longer

console.log(trunc(shorter));
// This is a sentence.
```

Comment: substr is way more efficient that split plus you are losing the punctuation mark which OP was asking to be included.

Comment: @AdrianBrand - good point on the end punctuation in the expected output (answer edited accordingly). As far as performance, generalizations are only occasionally useful - best to test specific approaches with specific datasets and environments if you have a situation that requires that level of optimization.

Comment: What do you mean by "generalizations are only occasionally useful". substr will only take the characters up to the first punctuation mark, split will create an array with the whole string and performance is greatly effected the longer the string and the more punctuation marks. There is no data set where using split on the punctuation marks gives better performance.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const checkString = str => str.substr(0, /[.?!]/.exec(str).index + 1).split(' ').filter((_, idx) => idx < 8).join(' ');

console.log(checkString("This is a sentence that is much longer than eight words, but only the first eight words will be outputted."));

console.log(checkString("This is a sentence. This is another sentence."));

console.log(checkString("This is a sentence? This is another sentence."));

console.log(checkString("This is a sentence! This is another sentence."));
```